# Would the site benefit from a "user has not performed basic research" close vote category?

Tags: discussion

Lately, I've noticed a lot of questions, especially by new users, which show a lack of minimal research effort, even in the form of looking in the "similar questions" list while writing a question.

This results in a load of low-quality (and not necessarily duplicated) content which is quickly downvoted and often either flagged for closure or close-voted within minutes.

Inevitably, this also results in users answering this question (whether in good faith or for some quick rep isn't very relevant); and as some of you may know, posting answers is generally discouraged because it hurts the overall quality of StackExchange sites by setting a precedent that even low-quality questions can receive high-quality answers.

Would StackOverflow benefit from having a dedicated item in the close-vote modal, and maybe even a dedicated review queue, for answers showing a lack of minimal research, and for reviewing those reported as such?

Comment: This question has been asked previously on this site more than once.

Comment: Kind of the same thing as lacks minimal understanding which was removed from being a close vote reason.

Comment: @NathanOliver can you link to background about why that was removed instead of being reworded? HovercraftFullOfEels: I'd found some similar questions, but none that addressed this issue directly, and none that brought up the point that answering poor questions should generally be avoided.

Comment: Stack Overflow would benefit from users dedicated to downvoting posts that have not performed basic research.

Comment: How about [Are there questions that are too trivial to answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309208/are-there-questions-that-are-too-trivial-to-answer) or as per @NathanOliver, [Can we please have the “Lacks Minimal Understanding” close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)

Comment: @Jules Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason

Comment: 99% of questions would fall under this close reason.

Answer (score 3):

We used to have a reason like that, and it was removed.

Realistically, you don't *know* what research a user has done.
If the question has been asked here before, just close-vote it as duplicate.

Comment: There was never a close reason for this.  Yes, you *can* determine if basic research hasn't been done on a question.  Not all questions that lack basic research are duplicates.

Comment: _"A reason **like** that"_ --> "Similar to". It's fine if you disagree, just downvote and ___move on___. I tried to be [subtle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346631/would-the-site-benefit-from-a-user-has-not-performed-basic-research-close-vote/346632?noredirect=1#comment463113_346632). Now please, stop forcing yourself on this answer like that.

Comment: So how are they alike?  How are they similar?  The close reason in the question is just as similar to the reason you're referring to as it is to "Too Broad" (because that's basically what that reason is).  So you're saying, "Didn't do basic research" is just like "Too Broad".  But they're *not* alike.  Again; it's not *a matter of opinion*, it's an objective fact that you're unequivocally incorrect about.

Comment: Cerbrus, @Servy - how 'bout, ya know, you both just agree to disagree since it's pretty clear neither of you is going to convince the other?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Agreeing to disagree is a thing that you do when there is a subjective matter of opinion to which it is acceptable for different people to hold different beliefs.  This is not a matter of opinion.  It's a statement of fact that has a single objectively correct answer.

Comment: @Servy Okay, then try this other thing called "giving up because you're *still* not going to convince each other and this is just polluting the comments now".

Comment: Just drop it. This isn't constructive. Servy, you're probably right, but this has gone beyond 'disagreeing' or 'you're wrong'. Vote as you may.

Comment: You're both equally wrong: we never had a "no basic research" close reason (that's what downvoting is for), and we *did* have an off-topic reason that was **widely misinterpreted** as being a "no basic research" close reason (which is why it was removed). No need to get insistent about your wrongness.

Comment: @Undo So knowingly making incorrect statements is constructive, but informing people that a statement is provably false isn't?

Comment: Guys, stop sending me notifications about a trivial discussion on a trivial answer on a question that was closed as duplicate a couple of minutes after it was posted. In other words, let's move on.