# Should I close question as Typo-Error if problem was missing reference?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, typographical-error

I see questions where problem is just missing reference (dll, nuget) or missing namespace in code. Hence, either code cannot compile or an exception at run time.

Are these questions on-topic? Or can those be closed as typo-error as shown in below screen shot?

[image: Screenshot]

If those are off-topic but the reason is incorrect, what is correct reason for closing the question?

The [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255567/5779732) similar question discuss about typo in code. I am not talking about typo in code.
I am talking about missing references. I agree the namespace is a "code". But here, I see namespace more as "reference" than just a code.

Comment: Is there a canonical reference that you can close the question as a duplicate of instead? This sounds like a common enough debugging problem that we ought to have a reference to point to.

Comment: The duplicate invites users to ask the question "Will the post (and its answer) ever benefit anyone else, or is it so specific to the OP's situation that it will only benefit him?" in order to see if that's the appropriate close reason. In this case, I think it's more a common error that can benefit others, in fact, it's probably been asked before and can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: The odds that there is no question about someone not having a reference or namespace are zero (in every single language).  Obviously someone has asked that question before, so you can close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @DavyM: Not exactly a duplicate. I have edited the question to add more explanation.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Does the answer not still cover both references and code as part of the general idea of what a typo is? It seems like your question already has an answer there, unless there's a fundamental difference between the typo explanation given there and what you need that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I think one of the answers in the proposed duplicate actually covers this pretty well: _"The key difference is whether it's a misunderstanding, or a mistype."_ If it's a misunderstanding, it is much more likely to be useful to future visitors.